# Reconnect disconnected socket.io with JWT authentication

Tags: javascript, socket.io, jwt

I'm using a JWT to authenticate with socket.io. Here is the **client** code:

```
const socket = io.connect(
            'ws://123.456.789.0:8500',
            {
                query: {
                    token: jwtToken
                },
                transports: ['websocket', 'polling']
            }
        );
```

Now, at some point the `jwtToken` expires and the connection disconnected from the **server**:

```
...
io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
    const isExpired = await checkExpireDateEveryMinute(socket.exp, 5);

    if (isExpired) {
        socket.disconnect();
    }

    await socket.on('query', async (data) => {

        ...

    });
});
```

Which is the proper way to reconnect from client with new generated JWT token? Couldn't find much resources on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a batter way is to use socket.io's middleware functionality, which will prevent the on("connection") callback from firing, if you call next() with an Error object. It will also transmit the error message to the frontend. You can send a fresh token this way, and reconnect.

Here is an example:

```
async function authenticate(socket,next){
    const isExpired = await checkExpireDateEveryMinute(socket.exp, 5);

    if(isExpired){
        const newToken = getNewToken()//Get a new token...
        next(new Error(newToken))//This will cause an error in your frontend, and pass the new token.
    }else{
        next();
    }
}
io.use(authenticate)//Register the middleware.
```

I have to point out something: you're doing "await" on socket.on(query,...), which makes no sense.

As for your frontend, it might look something like this:

```
function initSocket(token, url) {

  const socket = io.connect(url, {//Init the socket.
    query: {
      token
    }
  });

  return socket;
}

let socket = initSocket('someToken', 'http://localhost:8000')

socket.on('error', async (error) => {
  if(error === 'TOKEN_EXPIRED'){
    const newToken = await getToken();
    socket.close();
    socket = initSocket(newToken, 'http://localhost:8000')
  }
})
```

Note that you will need to re-register all events you have for your socket.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Actually I'm getting the token from another back-end via AJAX request and sending over node.js server from the front-end. But, if we follow the logic, I should send a token expiration error to the front-end without closing the connection, and from the front end I simply `socket.emit` the new token? Is that right?

Comment: once you get this error, you will just need to call your socket initiation function(assuming you have one), pass the new token, and reconnect again. it will be a new socket, with the new credentials.

Comment: The expiration come from server (whatever server). You solution won't work.